# Adding Fragments and Simple UI Elements significantly slows down Audio Processing Algo

Tags: android, audio

I am new to android and I am trying to build an APP to record audio, do FFT to get freq spectrum.

The buffer size of complete audio is 155 * 2048 
i.e. 155* AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(44100, mono_channel, PCM_16bit)

Each chunk from the recorder is of 2048 shorts , i convert type short into type double and pass it to the FFT library. The library returns me the real and imaginary part which i will use to construct the frequency spectrum. Then i append each chunk to an array.

Now here is the problem:

In app 1 there are no UI elements or Fragments just a simple basic button which is attach to a listener that execute an Async task for reading chunks from Audio.Recorder and does FFT on it chunk by chunk ( each chunk = 2048 short). This process (Recording and FFT) for 155 chunks with sample rate 44100 should take 7 seconds ( 2048 * 155 / 44100 ) but the task took around 9 seconds, which is a lag of 2 seconds (which is acceptable).

In app 2 there are 7 fragments with login and signup screen where each fragment is separate from each other and linked to main activity. The same code here does the task (recording and fft) for 155 * 2048 chunks in 40-45 seconds which means the lag is upto 33-37 seconds. This lag is too much for my purpose. What could be the cause of so much lag in app 2 and how can i reduce it ?

Following is the FFT Library Code and Complex Type Code
[FFT.java](https://gist.github.com/spandey2405/6b90a3d7311b0a8cb83893699a98c147) , [Complex.java](https://gist.github.com/spandey2405/eb1a30206176b9fb1e49c12ce7f6c965)

My application Code

```
private boolean is_recording = false;

    private AudioRecord recorder = null;
    int minimum_buffer_size = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

    int bufferSize = 155 * AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    private static final int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
    private Thread recordingThread = null;
    short[] audioBuffer = new short[bufferSize];

    MainTask recordTask;
    double finalData[];
    Complex[] fftArray;
    boolean recieved = false;

    int data_trigger_point = 10;
    int trigger_count = 0;
    double previous_level_1 ;
    double previous_level_2 ;
    double previous_level_3 ;

    int no_of_chunks_to_be_send = 30;
    int count = 0;
    short[] sendingBuffer   = new short[minimum_buffer_size * no_of_chunks_to_be_send];
    public static final int RequestPermissionCode = 1;

 mButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.submit);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (is_recording) {
                    mButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
                    stopRecodringWithoutTone();
                }
                else {
                    mButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wait);
                    is_recording = true;
                    recordTask = new MainTask();
                    recordTask.execute();
                }

            }


        });

    public class MainTask extends AsyncTask<Void, int[], Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {

                recorder = new AudioRecord(
                        MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT,
                        SAMPLE_RATE,
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                        minimum_buffer_size);

                recorder.startRecording();

                short[] buffer_recording          = new short[minimum_buffer_size];

                int recieve_counter = 0;
                while (is_recording) {
                    if (count < bufferSize) {
                        int bufferReadResult = recorder.read(buffer_recording, 0, minimum_buffer_size);
                        System.arraycopy(buffer_recording, 0, audioBuffer, count, buffer_recording.length);
                        count += bufferReadResult;
                        System.out.println(count);
                        finalData = convert_to_double(buffer_recording);
                        int [] magnitudes = processFFT(finalData);
                    }
                    else {
                        stopRecording();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("V1", "Recording Failed");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(int[]... magnitudes) {

        }

    }
    private int[] processFFT(double [] data){

        Complex[] fftTempArray = new Complex[finalData.length];
        for (int i=0; i<finalData.length; i++)
        {
            fftTempArray[i] = new Complex(finalData[i], 0);
        }
        fftArray = FFT.fft(fftTempArray);
        int [] magnitude = new int[fftArray.length/2];

        for (int i=0; i< fftArray.length/2; i++) {
            magnitude[i] = (int) fftArray[i].abs();
        }
        return magnitude;
    }
    private double[] convert_to_double(short data[]) {
        double[] transformed = new double[data.length];
        for (int j=0;j<data.length;j++) {
            transformed[j] = (double)data[j];
        }
        return transformed;

    }
    private void stopRecording() {

        if (null != recorder) {
            recorder.stop();
            postAudio(audioBuffer);
            recorder.release();
            is_recording = false;
            recorder = null;
            recordingThread = null;
            count = 0;
            recieved = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why there is a lag, however you can circumvent this problem : Run two async tasks, task 1 records the data and stores it in an array. 2nd async task takes chunks form this array and does FFT.

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask runs at a lower priority to make sure the UI thread will remain responsive. Thus more UI, more delay in `AsyncTask`

You're facing the delay because of the scheduling of `BACKGROUND` thread priority by the Linux cgroup that Android uses that has to live with 10% CPU time altogether.

If you go with `THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND + THREAD_PRIORITY_MORE_FAVORABLE` 
your thread will be lifted with 10% limitation.

> So your code will look like this:

```
  protected final Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        Process.setThreadPriority(THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND + THREAD_PRIORITY_MORE_FAVORABLE);
        ...//your code here
    }
```

If that doesn't work due to some reasons on next call of `doInBackground` because Android by default resets the priority. In that case, try using `Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_FOREGROUND`

Comment: @Saurabh Let me know the time consumed after you changed the priority and mark this answer as correct if you find this helpful.